# How properly setup Flask + pypugjs + sass?

Tags: python, flask, sass, libsass, pypugjs

I am developing some application with Flask and now I've decided to make the
whole process easier with use of [pypugjs](https://github.com/kakulukia/pypugjs) (it is python port of [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) template engine for JS) and SASS.  Installing and using pypugjs is easy and smooth, but now I do not know how use it with SASS properly.

I've read this
[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402360/cant-generate-all-css-file-from-sass-files-with-flask-assets),
it provides solution to Flask + SASS via
[Flask-Assets](https://flask-assets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and
[pyscss](https://github.com/Kronuz/pyScss).  And it works without `pypugjs`
pretty well, but with `pypugjs` I am unable to use `{% assets %}` tag.
So I simply decided to call `assets.build()` in Flask part. But it looks like some sort of transrectal solution:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_assets import Environment, Bundle
import pypugjs

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.add_extension('pypugjs.ext.jinja.PyPugJSExtension')

assets = Environment(app)
assets.url = app.static_url_path
assets.debug = True

scss = Bundle('sass/foo.scss', filters='pyscss', output='all.css')
assets.register('scss_all', scss)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    assets['scss_all'].build()
    return render_template('flask_hello.pug', test_fl="EMPEROR", test='false')
```

I tried to setup [Flask-Scss](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Scss/) (it also
use `pyscss` for SASS compilation) as a middleware. But the project looks
pretty dead (last commit was in 2015), and I failed to make it automatically
compile SASS files for me.

Then I tried to create [custom filter for pypugjs](https://github.com/kakulukia/pypugjs/blob/master/pypugjs/filters.py)
using [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass-python) (because it freshest
and most alive github repo from https://github.com/sass/libsass-python page).
It works if I am using it as an inline paste:

```
style
    :sass_it
        $primary-color: gold;
        body { background-color: $primary-color;}
```

And pypugjs even have an ability to import files via filters like
`include:my_filter filepath`, but flask prevents such includes of static files.
Constructions like `link(rel='stylesheet', href='static/bar.css'):filter` also
do not work.

I've tried to use libsass as a separate function in backend:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
# import pypugjs
import sass


app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.add_extension('pypugjs.ext.jinja.PyPugJSExtension')


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    sass.compile(dirname=('sass', 'css'), output_style='compressed')
    return render_template('flask_hello.pug', test_fl="EMPEROR", test='false')
```

But it no less transrectal than Flask-Assets approach above, and even more --
it does not merge multiple files into one.

And the last thing I've tried was [libsass with SassMiddleware](https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/frameworks/flask.html).
It works, but it works for single files only, it does not merge all my scss
files into one, despite that `site-packages/sassutils/builder.py` has
`build_directory()` and `build()` functions, it uses only `build_one()`.

I'll provide detailed example below, as a most relevant one.

Flask part:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from sassutils.wsgi import SassMiddleware

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.add_extension('pypugjs.ext.jinja.PyPugJSExtension')
app.wsgi_app = SassMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    'pypugtests': {'sass_path': 'static/sass',
                   'css_path': 'static/css',
                   'strip_extension': True,
                   },
})


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('flask_hello.pug', test_fl="EMPEROR", test='false')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

pypugjs part:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
    // scss generated
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='static/css/foo.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='static/css/bar.css')
  body
    h1.title PugJS - node template engine
    #container
      if (test == 'false')
        p You are amazing, #{test_fl}
      else
        p Get on it!
```

Dir structure:

```
pypugtests/
├── __init__.py
├── pypugtests.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bar.css
│   │   ├── bar.css.map
│   │   ├── foo.css
│   │   └── foo.css.map
│   └── sass
│       ├── bar.scss
│       └── foo.scss
└── templates
    └── flask_hello.pug
```

Files in css directory are created automatically.

So, is there a way to autocompile all scss files in sass directory into one css file?
Or I am doing all wrong and wanting strange things and I should use '@import'
instead?

**PS:** There is no `pypugjs` tag, and I lack of reputation to create one, so I'll use old project name -- `pyjade` in tag list.

Comment: Did you solve the problem or found good documentation?

Comment: @TobiasKolb nope, I had to manually convert SASS to CSS with console command each time. But maybe something has changed sine then.